# How to change scroll position right before navigating to new routes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I already have a working solution with react hooks that scrolls to the top of the page on route change but unfortunately this is not working for my use case.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

The problem is that i'm implementing infinite scrolling in some of my routes with the react-infinite-scroll-component package and on these routes an API call gets dispatched on `componentDidMount` hook to fetch initial data and also further API calls are triggered when the scroll position is midway through existing data.

The scroll position change seems to be happening right after the new component is rendered which results in simultaneous duplicate API calls. But if the scroll position is already at the top before changing routes then everything works fine.

I need a way to make sure that right before changing routes the scroll position goes to the top. What is the best way to do this? I have looked at almost every single post regarding scroll positioning with react-router but i can't seem to wrap my head around it. 
Any help will be appreciated.